# Center one element to another element with CSS (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `<a>` element styled as a button via Bootstrap. I want the text below it to be centered aligned with the button. How do I do this? I tried to center the text itself with a `<center>` tag, however this moved it to the center of the parent (`<div id="parent">`), not the center of the button. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<div id="parent">
    <a href="/personalised-payment-page/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-raised" style="max-width: 300px !important;">CREATE YOURS NOW</a><br>
    <b style="color: #388e3c;">(FREE - LIMITED PERIOD)</b>
</div>
```

Currently looks like this
[image: before image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

EDIT: I should emphasise that I don't want the button to move at all, just the green `<b>` text underneath to center itself under the button.

Comment: `<center>` is depreciated. so don't use that

Comment: I think `#parent{ text-align: center; }` should work for you.

Comment: I believe in his case the anchor button may be smaller then the `#parent` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your page.

```
#parent {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center
}
```

You can also use the following.  I don't have enough knowledge about the rest of your code to determine which would be best.

```
#parent {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: Why should he use position: absolute?

Comment: I believe in his case the anchor button may be smaller then the `#parent` element

Comment: Yes @LcSalazar is correct.  I'm assuming that the anchor button is smaller than the #parent element.  So setting the position to absolute makes the parent element the same size as the button in this situation.  You can also use display: inline-block;

Comment: This worked for me - the button didn't move but the `<b>` centered. Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `<a>` and `<b>` tag in a `display:inline-block` element, with the `text-align:center` property:

```
<div id="parent">
    <span style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;">
        <a href="/personalised-payment-page/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-raised" style="max-width: 300px !important;">CREATE YOURS NOW</a><br>
        <b style="color: #388e3c;">(FREE - LIMITED PERIOD)</b>
    </span>
</div>
```

*OBS: Avoid using inline styling*

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="parent" style="text-align:center">
    <a href="/personalised-payment-page/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-raised" style="max-width: 300px !important;">CREATE YOURS NOW</a><br>
    <b style="color: #388e3c;">(FREE - LIMITED PERIOD)</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
#parent {
    text-align: center
}
```

As already said center has been deprecated.

Comment: I believe in his case the anchor button may be smaller then the `#parent` element

Answer (score 0):

I would use this pattern if you wish to keep button on 300px width explicitly:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div style="max-width: 300px !important;" class="text-center">
    <a href="/personalised-payment-page/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-raised btn-block" >CREATE YOURS NOW</a>
    <b style="color: #388e3c;">(FREE - LIMITED PERIOD)</b>
   </div>
</div>
```